# Bootstrap fixed navbar - custom css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 framework and trying to adjust their fixed-top navbar. Essentially height, padding, color, etc.

HTML

```
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
```

I have been able to change the link properties through navbar-custom css but I can't find the list of what classes/id's the navbar-fixed-top uses.

I am bringing bootstrap in through CDN

EDIT

I'm trying to override the bootstrap defaults but can't figure out which values they are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should focus on your `navbar-custom` element. `navbar-fixed-top` isn't where you should adjust height, etc with overrides. You can apply it there but it's a better idea to keep it with your `custom` class, that's why you have it after all.

If you open up the Bootstrap CSS and search for `navbar-fixed-top` you'll see what I mean.

```css
.navbar.navbar-custom {
  height: 70px;
  background: #266080;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle,
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus {
  border: none;
  background: none;
}
.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: #fff;
}
.navbar-custom .collapse .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar-custom .collapse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-custom .collapse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
  background: none;
  color: #f00;
}
.navbar-custom .collapse .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
    background: #266080;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: oh ok, like I said I don't have the actual files I'm bringing them in dynamically. Couldn't find a css stylesheet, just examples

Comment: You should still be able to go into to the CDNs link:  https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css. Or whichever CDN you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple Fiddle with some of your needs:
https://jsfiddle.net/jvoqpsm3/

```
.navbar-fixed-top {
    background: #000000;
    height: 80px;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Just find the values you want to change and add them in your custom.css, just like I did.

Comment: is that the only value that navbar-fixed-top uses to change the navigation? there aren't any more specific ones like navbar-fixed-top .something .something?

Comment: @user3550879 Actually .navbar-fixed-top isn't setting the height, but you can override it in on that element if you want. Just think about, what you want to override and try it. It should work. On the a-element in the Navigation, you have to set the color separately, for example. It depends on the element.

Answer (score 0):

can you not just use:

```
.navbar.navbar-custom.navbar-fixed-top{
  height: 50px; //custom height
    ...
}
```

Comment: using height doesn't seem to change the height, I'm trying to override the bootstrap defaults but can't figure out which values they are using